# Find Out Who Downloaded iPhone App

Tags: iphone, app-store, itunes

From iTunesConnect we can get the total number of app downloads and updates.

On a particular date, we found that there was a sudden increase of app downloads, which was unexpected. We want to find out why and how this things happen.

So is it possible to know who downloads our iPhone app on a given date? Or whether it was involved on a certain kind of app promotion?

Fyi, our app uses internal logging to our server, however that only track app usage.

Answer (score 1):

There is framework called 'Flurry',integrate it with your app you can track your app's use.

link-http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Main_Page

See demo for how to use it.

Comment: our app already use Mixpanel to track user behavior. What we want to know here is who downloaded our app (and they probably don't use our app at all) and why there is download spike.

Answer (score 0):

Apple will not allow you to know the downloads statics using analytics. Looks like in your case, you are tracing download URL, which may not be the case that user is downloading. May be some one is promoting the download URL & you are getting spikes.

I would say, try to do a Smart Flurry Integration. I just had a dive into Mixpanel so can't say more about it. I would suggest to try this with your [Flurry integration](http://flurry.com).

Do a conditional logging like, if app is running for the first time, log below stuff, or else never log it. To do this, user `NSUserDefaults` intelligently.

1. Get the information of `identifierForVendor` from `UIDevice` class & log it
2. Also get the User's location, (Lat lang) & also log it using Flurry.
3. All other information like iOS version, device version, firmware version, flurry takes care.

This way you can make sure that your app has been downloaded at least. That is the only way I have made to confirm the downloads. People do run the app at least once after downloadig.

Hope that helps.